# How can paginated content be memcached/cleared effectively on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, pagination, memcached

I would like to memcache my paginated content on App Engine to reduce CPU time. I am using **cursors** to handle the pagination and the problem is when a new entity is added all of the memcached pages should be **cleared** so the content is fresh.

**How can this be done effectively?**

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.. I dont want do clear all my Memcache.. becouse i dont know how to remove only de pagination from memcache, if i use the cursorstring as key of memcache how could i remove it after?

Answer (score 1):

I use Ben Davies's magnificent [PagedQuery](http://code.google.com/p/he3-appengine-lib/wiki/PagedQuery) class to handle pagination. It transparently handles the cursors and the caching, so when I add a new item or delete and old item or otherwise invalidate the pages, all I have to do is call the `.clear()` method, and all of related memcached data is removed and the collection is re-paginated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked out the source, unfortunately it doesn't seem to cache the page content (query results). It only caches the query cursors and page count